# Embedded workflow without email sending

Tags: docusignapi

I'm a bit confused with embedded workflow.

From documents [Embedding: Initiate workflows directly within your app or website](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview) it says that *With Embedding you can seamlessly integrate DocuSign functionality into your app or website, allowing users to send and sign documents instantly instead of using email*.
I don't want spam users with additional emals, I just want to open URL in the browser for them to sign the document.

Embedded workflow receipt contains the [code - Signing from within your app](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/signing-from-your-app) (.net one) which sets `envDef.Status = "sent";`. This effectively sends singing request to the recipients' mail.
I want to avoid this and show only signing url. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- In an embedded signer/recipient scenario, setting the envelope status to SENT is equivalent to the envelope being created and ready for use. You can use the API to generate a signing URL to launch signing within your app. Your alternative to this is to create the envelope in DRAFT in the event you still have to add additional documents to it.
- In a remote/non-embedded scenario, I agree that once the envelope is SENT an email will be generated by DocuSign. However, not applicable to your workflow.

Comment: Is that possible to sigin draft document?

Comment: Also it says me `INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER` - ` Only 'sent' or 'created' (default) are allowed`

Comment: You cannot sign a draft envelope/document. The status you want to use to create a DRAFT envelope = created.

Comment: So the answer - this is not possible to have embedded workflow without email sending, correct?

Comment: Incorrect.  "Sent" in this context only means that recipients are activated.  If a recipient is "remote" (the default) then emails are sent.  If they are embedded/captive then an email is not sent, but you may then embed signing.  Technically in embedded signing you can choose whether DS should send an email but by default it is off.

Comment: Thank you guys, just tested - as soon as you provide `signer.ClientUserId` then it's considered as embedded workflow and email doesn't send. Last time I did something wrong and email was send.